# Compiling F# quotation to JS with WebSharper

Tags: f#, websharper

I need to compile a quotation into JS string (my main goal is to write MongoDB MapReduce job in F#). I found an [example](https://www.fssnip.net/rP/title/WebSharper-compile-a-quotation-to-JavaScript) code:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open WebSharper
type AR = IntelliFactory.Core.AssemblyResolution.AssemblyResolver
module FE = WebSharper.Compiler.FrontEnd

let compile (expr: Expr) : string option =
    let loader = FE.Loader.Create (AR.Create()) (eprintfn "%O")
    let options =
        { FE.Options.Default with
            References =
                List.map loader.LoadFile [
                    "WebSharper.Main.dll"
                    "WebSharper.Collections.dll"
                    "WebSharper.Control.dll"
                ] }
    let compiler = FE.Prepare options (eprintfn "%O")
    compiler.Compile expr
    |> Option.map (fun e -> e.ReadableJavaScript)
```

But the compiler output for a simple function, such as

```
<@ fun x -> x + 2 @>
```

is pretty ugly

```
(function()
{
var Global=this,Runtime=this.IntelliFactory.Runtime,EntryPoint;
 Runtime.Define(Global,{
  WebSharper:{
   EntryPoint:{
    Example:Runtime.Field(function()
    {
     return function(x)
     {
      return x+2;
     };
    })
   }
  }
 });
 Runtime.OnInit(function()
 {
  return EntryPoint=Runtime.Safe(Global.WebSharper.EntryPoint);
 });
 Runtime.OnLoad(function()
 {
  EntryPoint.Example();
  return;
 });
}());
```

I did not find any option to disable all that WebSharper stuff in the output. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. WebSharper is not just a transpiler, but a whole framework. It needs all that extra stuff for the framework to work. Try Fable.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Fable needs JS infrastructure to work, it's completely not what I want.

Comment: is serializing it to JSON using Newtonsoft/FsharpLau/Chiron/Fspickler/etc. not good enough? You actually want the JS code?

Comment: @s952163 I need to **compile** quotation, not **serialize** it.

Comment: Fable is the way to go.

Comment: @s952163 as I said, Fable needs npm and Babel, and I don't want my project to require that stuff.